# Youtube API - Title only

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I know that i can get the whole info about a video by using:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ID

but that outputs a lot of information and im using a regular expression to get the title out of it. I was wondering if there was a way to let that page only output the title and not all the other stuff that i dont need.

Comment: can you post the output?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this will help since I've never worked with youtube api before.  I just ran across this info yesterday.  According to http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/googleapis-how-google-builds-apis.pdf you can do a Partial Get (just search that pdf for "Partial Response") by using `fields=entry(title)` (though I think it's for searching for videos). By querying for the actual video id instead of a string it will return just that one video.

Example:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=[video_id]&max-results=1&fields=entry(title)&prettyprint=true
```

Comment: +1 good find. Partial retrieving is marked experimental though. Here is the docs: https://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial.html

Answer (score 4):

```
<?
$id = 'VIDEOID';
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$id}?fields=title"));

$title = (string)$xmlData->title;

echo $title;
```

Answer (score 2):

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[id]?fields=title

experimental but working.

Answer (score 1):

It returns an XML file so use [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse it.

Comment: i dont want to, i can get the title from that, i was asking for a way to let that page only output the title directly

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I don't think there is having looked through the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix search term with "title:", like this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q=title:<search term>
```